# Where the result of function call is kept if I pass it as parameter?

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory, c99, cpu-registers

```
uint32_t sum_a_b(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return a + b; 
}

uint32_t mul_c_d(uint32_t c, uint32_t d) {
    return c * d; 
}

int main(uint16_t argc, char **argv) {
    uint32_t e;
    e = mul_c_d(116, sum_a_b(17, 992));
    return 0;
}
```

Question is where the running machine is storing the result of call `sum_a_b(17, 992)` before passing it as second parameter to `mul_c_d` ?

Some "temporary variable" at stack?

Processor registers? Heap?

Where can I read about this?

Any difference with explicitly using the variable,

```
int main(uint16_t argc, char **argv) {
    uint32_t e, t;
    t = sum_a_b(17, 992);
    e = mul_c_d(116, t);
    return 0;
}
```

??

Unfortunately I don't have enough asm / disasm skills to check it directly....

Thank you!!

Comment: My guess, as it is an `uint32` return type, it will be kept purely in the accumulator register on most architectures and compilers. And generally pushed on the stack for the `mul_c_d` call, depending on compiler optimizations.

Comment: It depends on the compiler and the "application binary interface" (ABI). But consider that the result of the `mul_c_d` call is stored somewhere before it is assigned to `e`, as is the result of any subexpression before it is used in an outer expression (at least in an abstract sense). Such storage locations are anonymous and could be registers or memory.

Comment: As for using a variable to store the intermediate value. It may or may not get optimized out by the compiler, and that would probably depend on the optimization level selected for the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard doesn't specify where variables and values are stored, so the results will be very system-specific.

"Some "temporary variable" at stack?" Likely.
"Processor registers?" Likely.
"Heap?" No. The heap is only used when there's an explicit call to malloc or equivalent function. No known C compiler utilizes the heap implicitly.

> Unfortunately I don't have enough asm / disasm skills to check it directly

You don't need to know a lot of assembler to do that. Just toss your code into https://godbolt.org/, disable optimizations, and this is what you get (x86):

```
    mov     esi, 992
    mov     edi, 17
    call    sum_a_b
    mov     esi, eax
    mov     edi, 116
    call    mul_c_d
```

Now the only assembler we need to know is that instructions like `mov` stores the result in the left operand. Which is supposedly the rationale why `memcpy`, `strcpy` etc C functions store their results in the left operand too.

Then we need to know that esi, edi and eax are registers on x86. So it stores 992 and 17 in registers, then calls the function. After that, it goes to fetch something from a third register eax and places it in esi. So the return value from `sum_a_b` was stored in eax.

Now if I crank up optimizations, the whole `mul_c_d` call is replaced by `mov eax, 117044`. So the compiler was not just able to inline all function calls, it was also able to pre-calculate the result at compile-time too. So we can tell that it starts become increasingly irrelevant to know where the results are stored the more optimizations we enable.

> Where can I read about this?

All assemblers are kind of similar, so by learning the basics of any assembler, you get the rough idea of how all of them work. When you learn assembler, you learn how function calling conventions work "underneath the hood". Some resources can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/assembly/info